# Wordpress Multisite (style sheet and images not displaying under wp-content themes folder)

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I've created a multisite wordpress environment and made sites under it...

I copied over an existing theme I have to the multisite wp-content/theme folder to use it for all the sites.

My problem is that the paths are not showing up properly.  An example would be:
http://sitename.com/images/aim_informatics_logo.png

Where the image should be located in:
http://sitename.com/wp-content/themes/blankrightsidebar/images/aim_informatics_logo.png

The multisite set up is as follows:
Main Site (Multisite)
Blog
News
Events
Documents

For some reason the header.php file is not linking the paths correctly.  The theme I had is set up as a stand alone WP blog/page and it is linked under a directory... Example

www.sitename.com/blog

Where blog is my WP stuff saved.

Would appreciate if someone could help me with this.... I don't think changing each url path to: "sitename.com/wp-content/themes/blankrightsidebar/" would be a great answer.

Thanks in advance.

Update:
The code is:

```
<div id="header">
<div id="navContainer" class="container_12"><div class="headerpush"></div><!-- end headerpush -->

<h1 class="grid_3 logo"><a href="../index.php"><img src="../images/logo.png" /></a></h1>
<!-- end mainLogo -->
```

Stylesheet code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />
```

Basically, the structure of my site (multisite setup) is:
sitename (root)
   - wordpress files (wp-content, admin, includes, etc...)
        - Inside wp-content/theme/blankrightsidebar is where I store my theme files such as stylesheets, header.php etc.

Comment: Is it possible can you put code which is related logo or stylesheet from your multisite header file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your stylesheet link seems ok to me. But image link is not right. You may try this code:

```
            <div id="header">
        <div id="navContainer" class="container_12"><div class="headerpush"></div><!-- end headerpush -->

        <h1 class="grid_3 logo"><a href="<?php echo home_url( ); ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/logo.jpg" /></a></h1>
        <!-- end mainLogo -->
```

Comment: Basically I have to apply php codes within those links, right? Thank you... I have to dig back in to the original theme file and find useful codes there... If you have a suggestion in finding codes for WP, I'd be gladly appreciate it...

Comment: @tole78 thx. its better to use wordpress buit-in function. So that you can avoid unexpected error. you can get usefull information about wordpress and its buit-in function in this link: http://codex.wordpress.org/. This site is very helpful.